# find with multiple exec-statements where some exec-statements per found inode appear to be executed >1 times

Tags: linux, find, gnu

The following command

```
mkdir -p /tmp/test/foo /tmp/test/bar && \
find /tmp/test/ -mindepth 1 -type d \
-exec echo Deleting "{}" \; \
-exec rm -rv "{}" \;
```

I'd expect to print

```
Deleting /tmp/test/foo
removed directory '/tmp/test/foo'
Deleting /tmp/test/bar
removed directory '/tmp/test/bar'
```

(per 1st `-exec` statement)
and delete respective directories (per 2nd `-exec` statement).
Well, technically this is indeed what's happening and being printed on stdout - but there're 2 additional lines on stderr.

```
Deleting /tmp/test/foo
removed directory '/tmp/test/foo'
find: ‘/tmp/test/foo’: No such file or directory
Deleting /tmp/test/bar
removed directory '/tmp/test/bar'
find: ‘/tmp/test/bar’: No such file or directory
```

So it /seems/ the 2nd `-exec`-statement calling `rm -rv` is issued twice.

- Why / What's exactly happening here?
- How do I achieve what I'd actually expect from above command?

Comment: You are deleting directories and `find` is wanting to enter the directories to see if there is any work to be done in them. Add a `-depth` flag to do a depth-first walk of the tree?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## TL;DR

You are being confused by warning messages from `find` which look similar to error messages from `rm` into thinking that rm is being invoked multiple times per directory when it is not. Adding a `-depth` to the `find` command will stop the warnings and give the expected output.

## Explanation

It would be clearer if you had a slightly more complicated directory structure. You currently have

```
$ tree /tmp/test
/tmp/test
├── bar
└── foo
```

but if you had say

```
/tmp/test
├── bar
└── foo
    └── wibble
        └── hello.txt
```

then you can see that your example find command doesn't really make a lot of sense. The order that files are found within a directory is **not defined**, but let us assume that it finds `foo` first and then `bar`. The command will first remove the foo subtree, so will remove /tmp/test/foo/wibble/hello.txt, /tmp/test/foo/wibble and then /tmp/test/foo. It will then attempt to process the `foo` directory which it has just removed, prompting it to produce a warning message. It will then proceed to the next thing in /tmp/test, which is `bar`. It removes it, and then attempts to enter the `bar` directory it has just removed and again prints a warning message.

If you add a `-depth` to the find command then directories are processed **after** their sub-directories. So the order would be /tmp/test/foo/wibble (which would remove /tmp/test/foo/wibble/hello.txt and /tmp/test/foo/wibble), then /tmp/test/foo (which would remove the now empty /tmp/test/foo directory) and then /tmp/test/bar (which would remove the /tmp/test/bar directory).

Comment: Option `-prune` (if available) also makes sense with `rm -r` to not descend at all.

Comment: @Freddy I totally agree. I thought of mentioning it but didn't because it is not generally applicable. For example if instead of removing directories files were being moved to another location.